# Im trying to run a js script on the blockchain using hardhat ,it throws an error whenever I run it on the command line

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, chai

This is the following error I get when running the command "npx hardhat --network localhost scripts/1_deploy.js"

```
HeadersTimeoutError: Headers Timeout Error
    at Timeout.onParserTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/mnt/g/ONLINE_COURSE/project/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/undici/lib/client.js:902:28)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:561:11)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  code: 'UND_ERR_HEADERS_TIMEOUT'
}
```

I dont know the fix to this Kindly help.

The script I'm trying to run

```
// Fetch contract to deploy
  const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory('Token')
  const Exchange = await ethers.getContractFactory('Exchange')

  // Fetch accounts
  const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()

  console.log(`Accounts fetched:\n${accounts[0].address}\n${accounts[1].address}\n`)

  // Deploy contracts
  const edge = await Token.deploy('EDGE University', 'EDGE', '1000000')
  await edge.deployed()
  console.log(`EDGE Deployed to: ${edge.address}`)

  const mETH = await Token.deploy('mETH', 'mETH', '1000000')
  await mETH.deployed()
  console.log(`mETH Deployed to: ${mETH.address}`)

  const mDAI = await Token.deploy('mDAI', 'mDAI', '1000000')
  await mDAI.deployed()
  console.log(`mDAI Deployed to: ${mDAI.address}`)

  const exchange = await Exchange.deploy(accounts[1].address, 10)
  await exchange.deployed()
  console.log(`Exchange Deployed to: ${exchange.address}`)
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Also I'm using chai matchers....

Comment: That was my first thought, you don't have node running

Comment: @AlwinTomy You should add that as answer so we could mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Such a silly mistake by me ,after running "npx hardhat node", I would stop running it .It works now